# Protractor - How to set a default typing language in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I want to set a default typing language inside my conf file.

When I run my test cases locally I can't switch the keyboard language during the running because it changes the typing language for the protractor as well the tests are fail.

Please let me know if you have any solution for this,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
chromeOptions: {
  // How to set browser language (menus & so on)
  args: [ 'lang=fr-FR' ],
  // How to set Accept-Language header
  prefs: {
    intl: { accept_languages: "fr-FR" },
},
```

or

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      args: ['--lang=CS'] 
    }   
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox:

```
'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        prefs: {
          'intl.accept_languages': 'pt'
        }
      }
```

Chrome:

```
'chromeOptions': {
        args: ['--langPT-Br']
       }
```